# How to construct a vector of queues?

Tags: c++

I need to construct a crawler working with `front_queues` and `back_queues`, which are vectors of queues. I've seen solutions in this question [Vector of queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758456/vector-of-queues) but my compiler complains the `vec` needs a constructor.

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

vector<queue<int> > vec;
vec.push_back( queue<int>(0) );
// ^
// error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘.’ token
```

Comment: Does a `std::queue` have a constructor that takes a single `int`?

Comment: @Galik it's a typo. It shouldn't accept any pass-in variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put function calls inside blocks.

**Try adding a `main` function :**

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<queue<int> > vec;
    queue<int>          q;

    vec.push_back(q);
    return (0);
}
```

**`queue`doesn't have initializer list :**

According to `queue`'s constructor reference ([Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/queue/)), you can't use `queue<int>(0)` because no proper constructor would match.
However, you can use `queue<int>()`. It will create an empty queue.
Take a look at this online example : https://ideone.com/RbT1pD