# How to push queue into a vector of queues when vector size is not constant?

Tags: c++, vector, queue

Using ([Vector of queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758456/vector-of-queues)) as reference, I was able to create a vector of queues. However, in the example:

```
vector<queue<int>> vec; // vector of queues
vec.push_back(queue<int>()); // add a queue
vec[0].push(1); // push 1 into queue number 0.
```

When I try executing the second line that uses push_back, a loop is created in my program.

In my code, the size of the vector depends on N. I am trying to push a queue onto each vector index but no luck.

```
std::vector<std::queue<int>>station(N);
std::vector<std::queue<int>>::const_iterator iter;

    for(iter = station.begin(); iter != station.end(); iter++) {
    station.push_back(std::queue<int>());  //loop occurs here
    }
```

Help!

Comment: You're iterating over the `vector` and mutating it at the same time by adding elements to it. What's the point of the `for` loop?

Comment: Use the constructor? `vector<queue<int>>(N, queue<int>{});`

Comment: Each vector index already has a queue. You initialize it with `std::vector<std::queue<int>>station(N);` so the vector has `N` queues in it.

Comment: @nitronoid `vector<queue<int>>(N);` will suffice.  No need to specify `queue<int>{}` as the value to initialize them with, as the new elements will be default-constructed by default.

Comment: @Praetorian thanks for pointing out the for loop that was doing nothing. I had to dive down the rabbit hole to really understand nested containers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks! That reassurance really was what I needed to know I was on the right path